# FIND_IN_SET with Alias name

Tags: mysql

I want to get particular days with comma seperated so using group contact.My query like this

```
   select doc,group_concat(tab.days) as group_days FROM tab where doc='G9AoP58ENTOwGBqo' AND FIND_IN_SET('sun',group_days);
```

But not getting error.

```
    #1054 - Unknown column 'group_days' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: You can't use aliases in WHERE clause

Comment: so how to write this @Jens

Comment: try to use HAVING clause: where doc='G9AoP58ENTOwGBqo' HAVING FIND_IN_SET('sun',group_days);

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This query would return 0 or 1 rows at most (after fixing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using `group_concat(tab.days)` as parameter for `FIND_IN_SET()` function instead of alias

```
select * from
(
   select doc,group_concat(tab.days) as group_days FROM tab 
   where doc='G9AoP58ENTOwGBqo' 
   group by doc
)A
where FIND_IN_SET('sun',group_days);
```

Comment: no  getting error @fa06 #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: sure, please vote my question some one downvote to my question

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use column aliases inside select on Where, Group By, Order by clauses. You need to use subquery for this. Check my answer below:

Try in this way

```
 select 
   doc,
   group_concat(tab.days) as group_days 
 FROM tab 
 where 
   doc='G9AoP58ENTOwGBqo' AND 
   FIND_IN_SET('sun',group_concat(tab.days));
```

or alternatively

```
 select * from 
 (
   select 
     doc,
     group_concat(tab.days) as group_days 
   FROM tab 
   where 
     doc='G9AoP58ENTOwGBqo'
 )
 where  
   FIND_IN_SET('sun',group_days );
```

Comment: Do not only write *Try in this way* Explain what you have changed and why